# Logic problem: Array of JS objects -checking all object.properties are not undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Given the following vue.js object:

```
FormattedData: Object
    1: Object
        approved: true
    2: Object
        approved: undefined
    3: Object
        approved: false
    4: Object
        approved: true
```

Looking for a sensible/eloquent way to iterate through the object property `approved` and return false if any remain undefined.

This is the solution at present:

```
checkAllApproved() {
    let allApproved = false;
    for(let design in this.orderInfo.FormattedData) {
        if(this.orderInfo.FormattedData.hasOwnProperty(design)) {
            allApproved = this.orderInfo.FormattedData[design].approved;
        }
        if(typeof allApproved == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this solution? Also can you give an example of `FormattedData` instead of a schema?

Comment: This solution works as intended.  Perhaps this was a post more suited to code review?  I am unfamiliar with some of the nuance of JavaScript and considered perhaps there was a better way than stringifying the variable state `undefined` and checking against that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.`some` to test if any element in the array has a specified conditional parameter.

```
vue_data.some(({approved}) => approved === undefined);
```

```js
let vue_data = [{approved: false},{approved: undefined},{approved: true}],
vue_data2 = [{approved: false},{approved: true},{approved: true}],

r = vue_data.some(({approved}) => approved === undefined),
r2 = vue_data2.some(({approved}) => approved === undefined);


console.log(r ? "data=>something is undefined" : "data=>everything is defined");
console.log(r2 ? "data2=>something is undefined" : "data2=>everything is defined");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
checkAllApproved() {
    return Object.values(this.orderInfo.FormattedData).every(({approved})=>
        typeof approved !== 'undefined')
}
```

the every() function will return true only if the callback,that extracts `{approved}` property out of the value object, will return true for **all** the items in the array we created: `Object.values(this.orderInfo.FormattedData)` which is simply an array made out of all the values of `this.orderInfo.FormattedData` object.

more about methods like [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [every()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp)